# dont Show Parent DataTable If they have not child in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, datagridview

i will try build some cascade datagridview

Layer

layerID,LayerName (LayerID = PK )

Gor

LayerID , GorID , GorName ( GorID = PK and LayerID = FK )

Gru

GorID , GruID , GruName ( GruID = Pk and GorID = FK )

i start with this code

```
using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
            {

                DGVCharts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;


                var result = from layer in db.LayerRepository.Get()
                             join gor in db.GorRepository.Get() on layer.LayerID equals gor.LayerID

                             select new
                             {
                                 layer.LayerID,
                                 layer.LayerName,
                                 gor.GorID,
                                 gor.GorNumber,
                             };
                DGVCharts.DataSource = result.ToList();

            }
```

after i use top code i see this and its ok
[image]

now i will try load more colum i grow my code to this

```
using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
            {

                DGVCharts.AutoGenerateColumns = false;


                var result = from layer in db.LayerRepository.Get()
                             join gor in db.GorRepository.Get() on layer.LayerID equals gor.LayerID
                             join gru in db.GruRepository.Get() on gor.GorID equals gru.GorID
                             select new
                             {
                                 layer.LayerID,
                                 layer.LayerName,
                                 gor.GorID,
                                 gor.GorNumber,
                                 gru.GruID,
                                 gru.GruNumber
                             };
                DGVCharts.DataSource = result.ToList();

            }
```

after update my code i see this

[image]

where is manager in (Gor Colum) ??
manager no child and i cant see manager in my datagridview !

how i can see manager too ?

Comment: what is the difference between ``GordanId`` and  ``GorId``?

Comment: @Sajid wrong type for here i fix it now

Comment: i think the ``GorId`` for manager not exist in the ``Gru`` table, so in this case you can use left join for the second query.

Comment: @Sajid no manager not exist in the Gru Table how i can write left join ? i know code with SQL but i dont know how use it with Linq

Comment: there is an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: @Sajid this example not work !

Comment: *no manager not exist in the Gru Table* this mean manager exist or not exist in Gru Table?can you put what have you tried?

Comment: @Sajid manager is not exist in Gru table ( bcs manager = manager team ) and tree cut there. i will try use Left Join , but if i use Join then Left Join this is not work or i dont know how write code ( left join work solo ) and ( join work solo like this code ) but if i use both ( not work ! )

Comment: i'm simulating your tables and i'm adding an answer for *linq to object*, should be the same thing for *linqToEnities*, can you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [**Left join**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins), you can get `manager` if not has any relation in `Gru` Table.
I'm testing the following code for *LinqToObject* : `

1 - Creating test classes:

```
public class Layer
{
    public int LayerId { get; set; }
    public string LayerName { get; set; }
}
public class Gor
{
    public int GorId { get; set; }
    public int LayerId { get; set; }
    public string GorName { get; set; }
}
public class Gru
{
    public int GruId { get; set; }
    public int GorId { get; set; }
    public string GruName { get; set; }
}
public class Das
{
    public int DasId { get; set; }
    public int GruId { get; set; }
    public string DasName { get; set; }
}
```

2 - Initializing the collections:

```
List<Layer> layers = new List<Layer>
{
    new Layer{LayerId=1, LayerName="Main"}
};

List<Gor> gors = new List<Gor>
{
    new Gor{GorId=1, GorName="team01", LayerId=1},
    new Gor{GorId=2, GorName="team02", LayerId=1},
    new Gor{GorId=3, GorName="manager", LayerId=1},
};

List<Gru> grus = new List<Gru>
{
    new Gru{GruId=1, GruName="leader", GorId=1},
    new Gru{GruId=2, GruName="co-leader", GorId=1},
    new Gru{GruId=3, GruName="01", GorId=1},
    new Gru{GruId=4, GruName="leader", GorId=2},
    new Gru{GruId=5, GruName="co-leader", GorId=2},
    new Gru{GruId=6, GruName="01", GorId=2},
};
List<Das> dasList = new List<Das>
{
    new Das{DasId=1, DasName="das1", GruId=1},
    new Das{DasId=2, DasName="das2", GruId=5},
};
```

3 - Linq request:

```
var result = (from layer in layers
              join gor in gors on layer.LayerId equals gor.LayerId
              join gru in grus on gor.GorId equals gru.GorId into leftedGrus
              from leftedGru in leftedGrus.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join das in dasList on leftedGru?.GruId equals das.GruId into leftDasList
              from leftDas in leftDasList.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                  layer.LayerId,
                  layer.LayerName,
                  gor.GorId,
                  gor.GorName,
                  leftedGru?.GruId,
                  leftedGru?.GruName,
                  leftDas?.DasId,
                  leftDas?.DasName
              }).ToList();
```

4 - Demo

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Layer: {item.LayerId}::{item.LayerName}," +
        $"Gor: {item.GorId}::{item.GorName},Gru: {item.GruId}::{item.GruName}" +
        $",Das: {item.DasId}::{item.DasName}");
}
```

5 - Result

```
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 1::team01, Gru: 1::leader   ,Das: 1::das1
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 1::team01, Gru: 2::co-leader,Das:  ::
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 1::team01, Gru: 3::01       ,Das:  ::
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 2::team02, Gru: 4::leader   ,Das:  ::
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 2::team02, Gru: 5::co-leader,Das: 2::das2
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 2::team02, Gru: 6::01       ,Das:  ::
Layer: 1::Main,Gor: 3::manager,Gru:  ::         ,Das:  ::
```

Note that, `GruId` and `GruName` are null because no `manager` in `Gru` Table.

I hope this help you fix the issue.

Comment: this simulator is work, and my problem is fix but now i have new problem ! if i have 1 more table then other table not work... this is real tables Layer -> Gor -> Gru -> Das -> Group
this is work for 1 table ( Gru ) now i if i want join Das ( join not work ) say ( ID is not exist )...I was completely confused, I wish I had used Visual Basic and SQL, which I have mastered completely. 

please tell me in LINQ and C# how left join work with 2 or 3 table ( this is just work for 1 table ) i need really cry like little girl now ( +10 days i stop here for 5 combo box )

Comment: @AliZangeneh i have updated the answer,i hope this help, tell me if this exactly what you want, if not can you add some example for ``das`` table and the relationship between it and ``Gru`` table please

Comment: not work but thanks, The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.

Comment: @AliZangeneh you're welcome!. you can add an example and relationShip between tables, i'm just suggesting the ``Das`` table, i don't know how it's look like.

Comment: i can give u access to my program, can you see it and tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: @AliZangeneh ok.

Comment: how i can give u access ? how i can chat with you ? this is my email ali.zangeneh.ir@gmail.com

Comment: are you here ? Sajid ?

Comment: @AliZangeneh i have sent you an invitation by hangout. you can accept and send me your questions...

Comment: i not receive you invite

Comment: @AliZangeneh, i have sent you an email :) can you confirm this.